# 'VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR' error while trying to install Windows XP in VirtualBox

Tags: installation, 13.04, virtualbox

I install the application using the .deb, but I can't get a virtual machine to boot. How to install it correctly from the beginning?

Opening my newly-created XP machine yields this message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows ******* ****s.

VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR. (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your error message (`VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR.`) shows that either your processor does not support VT-x or it is disabled in your BIOS.

To start your VM you have to configure your VM with VT-x disabled. This can be done by selecting the VM click on *Change* then select *System* and on the tab *Acceleration* you can disable *VT-x/AMD-V* for the VM.

After that the VM should start.

(Please note that the tabs and names could be different as I use a German localized VirtualBox.)

Comment: The BIOS setting did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting your instance on your Oracle VM VirtualBox Player, go to settings, system, acceleration, and un-check "Enable VT-x/AMD-V". Start your instance and you should no longer see this error.

This answer https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=43403#p219282 solved it!